# risks of upgrading to Windows 8?

Tags: wpf, winforms, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, webforms

I am a .NET/ C# desktop & web developer. My computer has fried, and I am getting a new one. I am being pushed in the direction of Windows 8 for the OS - although I am very hesitant to move from Windows 7. I am wondering if any developers have already done this upgrade, and if so, what headaches or pitfalls might I run into?

Specifically - I am asking if Windows 8 has any conflicts with any of the development tools I would be using: Visual Studio 2010/2012, IIS, ASP.NET Web applications, WinForms & WPF applications, DevExpress controls, etc. Should this be a seamless transition - has anyone run into any issues with these tools or otherwise something that I might not have thought of by upgrading my OS version?

Comment: I've done the upgrade, went smoothly. Also not sure if this is on-topic or not.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks. Do you do any web development and are there any concerns with IIS setups/ versions? Also, where can I ask this question if not here? thanks again

Comment: Maybe superuser? It's really broad, I mean - it is _my_ personal experience that everything went smoothly, I had no problems with VisualStudio with ReSharper, SQL Developer and IIS which are the tools I use. Migration was smooth and installation was similar. I'm not sure if you can get a definitive answer - I mean, if someone did an actual study talking to lots of developers, or summing up the differences that would be nice, but I doubt such a study exists. Also can always dual boot. I do have Windows 7 installed in a VM, but that's just for IE8 and IE9 testing :)

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: This is a developer-oriented question after all. The main aspect that most would take issue with isn't its topic matter but possibly its subjectivity.

Comment: I've rephrased my question to make it clear that it's not opinion based, I am just looking for hard facts on people who have upgraded to Windows 8 and did they have any issues with the development tools I mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Based on my experience it's basically the same for developers. Everything such as Visual Studio works the same, except that you got IE 10 and also every time you have to launch an application you have to go back to the tile screen, which I find annoying but I create shortcuts for them on the desktop. Then there isn't much difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's apps like the free [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) that will bring back some of the feel of earlier windows versions like the start menu.

Comment: I think OP is asking from a development perspective, as in "Will my programming tools work as a C# web developer using the standard stack" . Probably not asking about the start menu.

Comment: Developers will appreciate a start menu rather than going back to the tile screen all the time.